# Docker xterm.js attach

Tags: docker, websocket, docker-api, xtermjs

I'm trying to build a simple in-browser shell using Docker and xterm.js. I've correctly hooked up the frontend using xterm.js's [attach](https://xtermjs.org/docs/api/addons/attach/) addon.

How does one connect to Docker via websockets?

Comment: What happens when you use the demo code from the application?

Comment: I can use the demo code to hook up to a "wss://..." endpoint correctly. (I verified with echo.websockets.org.) But I don't know how to set up docker to serve from the endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a Docker API >= 1.28, you cannot connect straight to it with xterm.js, since Docker changed their WebSocket protocol from text to binary .

There is an open xterm.js issue for that: https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/883.